# Ambiguous reference to member 'joinWithSeparator' in swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google's '`reverseGeocodeCoordinate`' to get address based on latitude and longitude.
I'm getting the following error in the implementation

> Ambiguous reference to member 'joinWithSeparator'

Below is my implementation:

```
let aGMSGeocoder: GMSGeocoder = GMSGeocoder()
aGMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.45134626, 78.39304448)) {
    (let gmsReverseGeocodeResponse: GMSReverseGeocodeResponse!, let error: NSError!) -> Void in

    let gmsAddress: GMSAddress = gmsReverseGeocodeResponse.firstResult()
    print("lines=\(gmsAddress.lines)")
    let addressString = gmsAddress.lines.joinWithSeparator("")
    print("addressString=\(addressString)")

}
```

I'm trying to create a `addressString` with the elements in array '`gmsAddress.lines`', but end up with an error message.

Implemented some sample snippet to test '`joinWithSeparator`'

```
let sampleArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let joinedString = sampleArray.joinWithSeparator("")
print("joinedString=\(joinedString)")
```

It succeeded.
What I observe is, '`sampleArray`' is an array of elements of type `String`, but '`gmsAddress.lines`' is an array of elements of type '`AnyObject`', Found in '`GMSAddress`' library:

```
/** An array of NSString containing formatted lines of the address. May be nil. */
public var lines: [AnyObject]! { get }
```

So, What are the possible ways to achieve the following line without looping the array:

```
let addressString = gmsAddress.lines.joinWithSeparator("")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is ambiguous because the array can contain `AnyObject` meaning every object in the array could be of a different type. Therefore the compiler can't know in advance whether any two objects in the array can be joined.

The reason your `sampleArray` works is that it has been implicitly determined to be an array of strings.

If you know for a fact that every element in the `lines` array is a string you can force downcast it to an array of strings:

```
let addressString = (gmsAddress.lines as! [String]).joinWithSeparator("")
```

Though it's probably worthwhile being safe about this and checking first.

```
if let lines = gmsAddress.lines as? [String] {
    let addressString = lines.joinWithSeparator(", ")

    ...
}
```